# Formatting SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS outputs when “\n” are embedded as Text

Tags: mysql, shell, sed, awk, newline

I am referring to this [link](http://www.chriscalender.com/?p=1110)

I have an output via this command:

`mysql -e "show engine innodb status" -u -p database > mydumpfile.txt`

However, any editor I use (less, vim, kwrite) is showing the `\n` instead of a real new line.

How can I accomplish the replacement with sed, awk or any other tool in a shell?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following syntax of sed.

```
sed -i -e 's|\\n|\n|g' mydumpfile.txt
```

If you want the direct output properly from mysql then use --table option in mysql command.

```
mysql --table -e "show engine innodb status" -u -p database > mydumpfile.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Try simply adding `\G` to the SQL command, for example:

`mysql -e "show engine innodb status\G" -u -p database > mydumpfile.txt`

Or try running the mysql client with the `-r` (or `--raw`) switch.

`mysql -re "show engine innodb status" -u -p database > mydumpfile.txt`

With either of these methods, you can also skip the intermediate file and just pipe into `less`. Such as:

`mysql -re "show engine innodb status" -u -p database | less`

Side note, specifying the database is not necessary. I included it only for parity to your question.  If you also have setup a my.cnf file, and therefore don't need to enter a password, you can shorten this to:

`mysql -re "show engine innodb status" | less`